# Python module installed properly but standard function not working in web2py

Tags: python-2.7, web2py, pafy

I am using Web2Py and want to use module pafy. so i first wrote the simple code in localhost which was

```
import pafy
video = pafy.new("Here i wrote the URL of the youtube video which i want to get")
```

this is working in localhost but in pythonanywhere it is not working but module was installed by me and also import pafy does not showing any error and if i removed the code line video = pafy.new("URL") the error is also removed.
the error which i got is as given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tushar992/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/tushar992/web2py/applications/ytd/controllers/default.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/home/tushar992/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/tushar992/web2py/applications/ytd/controllers/default.py", line 10, in second
    video = pafy.new(dlink)
  File "/home/tushar992/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 145, in new
    return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, signature, size, callback)
  File "/home/tushar992/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 1076, in __init__
    self.fetch_basic()
  File "/home/tushar992/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 1119, in fetch_basic
    self.dash = _extract_dash(self._dashurl)
  File "/home/tushar992/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 302, in _extract_dash
    dashdata = fetch_decode(dashurl)
  File "/home/tushar992/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 97, in fetch_decode
    raise e
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Looks like Youtube is returning a 403: Forbidden response. Are you sure the exact same URL works when running on localhost?

Comment: yes i am sure i am using the same code and actually i just "pack all" the app then upload it to the web2py in pythonanywhere. and i don't know whether it matter or not my localhost running python 2.7.7 and pythonanywhere running python 2.7.6

Comment: Maybe YouTube is blocking the pafy API key or user agent from the PythonAnywhere IP address for some reason.

Comment: ThankYou for the help, Now problem is solved and the exact problem was which i get to know now by the pythonanywhere staff is "One of the servers that Pafy uses was blocked by pythonanywhere proxy. they have added it to the whitelist." and after they added it now my code working properly

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here. If you are using a free account this may be because pafy is trying to access a url that is not on our whitelist.

We do have a bunch of other google api endpoints already in our whitelist, and I know that we just added googlevideo.com to it recently, so double check if you still get an access denied error now.

If you are still having problems and can figure out what the url is, send us an email/click feedback from your dashboard and we will be happy to whitelist any official api's.

Answer (score 0):

```js
default_options = {"language": LANGUAGE, "timeout": 3}

def authorize(table, record_id):
    myrecord = db[table][record_id]
    if not ((myrecord.user_id == auth.user_id) or (auth.has_membership(role="manager"))):
        raise HTTP(403, T("The requested action could not be performed. You must own the record or be in the managers list"), lazy=False)

if auth.is_logged_in():
    if not session.options:
        user_options = db(db.option.user_id==auth.user_id).select().first()
        if not user_options:
            db.option.insert(user_id=auth.user_id,
                             language=default_options["language"],
                             timeout=default_options["timeout"])
            session.options = default_options
        else:
            session.options = user_options.as_dict()
elif (not session.options):
    session.options = default_options
    
if request.function in ["show", "subtitles", "slides"]:
    response.files.append(URL(c='static', f="js/popcorn_complete.js"))
    response.files.append(URL(c='static', f="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"))
    response.files.append(URL(c='static', f="css/video.css"))


def index():
    """
    example action using the internationalization operator T and flash
    rendered by views/default/index.html or views/generic.html
    response.flash = "Welcome to web2py!"
    response.files.append(URL(c='static',f="js/popcorn_complete.js"))
    video = "2012_11_16_10_49_42_00194_480p_60s"
    videos = [#"http://www.sistemasagiles.com.ar/soft/00194_480_html5.webm",
              URL(c='static',f="videos/%s%s" % (video, ext))
              for ext in ('_fast.mp4', '.webm', '.ogv')
              ]
    slides = [
        {'href': '',
         'src': URL(c='static',f='slides/flask-pycon_2012-%d.png' % i),
         'text': 'slide %d' % i,
         'start': i*3,
         'end': i*3+3,
         }  for i in range(15)]
    subtitles = [
        {'text': 'subtitle %d bla bla bla' % i,
         'start': i*3,
         'end': i*3+3,
         }  for i in range(15)]
    return dict(videos=videos, slides=slides, subtitles=subtitles)
    """
    videos = db(db.video).select()
    return dict(videos=videos)


@auth.requires_login()
def slides():
    mylanguage = session.options["language"]
    if not mylanguage: response.flash = T("No language selected! Please visit the Setup page")
    video = db.video[request.args(1)]
    sources = db(db.source.video_id==request.args(1)).select()

    sq = db.presentation.user_id == auth.user_id
    sq &= db.presentation.video_id == request.args(1)
    sq &= db.presentation.language == mylanguage
    presentation = db(sq).select().first()

    if presentation is None:
        presentation_id = db.presentation.insert(user_id=auth.user_id,
                                                 video_id=request.args(1),
                                                 language=mylanguage,
                                                 title=video.title)

        # Fill presentation with previous slides
        other_slides = db((db.presentation.video_id==request.args(1)) & \
                        (db.presentation.language==mylanguage) & \
                        (db.presentation.id!=presentation_id)).select()
        slides_qties = dict()

        for oslide in other_slides:
            subcount = db(db.slide.presentation_id==oslide.id).count()
            slides_qties[subcount] = oslide.id

        if len(slides_qties) > 0:
            other_slides_id = slides_qties[max(slides_qties)]
            other_slides = db(db.slide.presentation_id==other_slides_id).select()
            for other_slide in other_slides:
                oslide = other_slide.as_dict()
                del(oslide["id"])
                del(oslide["presentation_id"])
                del(oslide["vurl"])
                oslide["presentation_id"] = presentation_id
                db.slide.insert(**oslide)
        else:
            # This is the first presentation for this language
            # set as default
            db.presentation[presentation_id].update_record(auto=True)
    else:
        presentation_id = presentation.id

    slides_set = db((db.slide.presentation_id==presentation_id)&(db.slide.template==False))
    slides = slides_set.select()
    templates = db((db.slide.presentation_id==presentation_id)&(db.slide.template==True)).select()

    # Custom form for editing slides client-side
    db.slide.clones.requires = CLONES_SLIDE(presentation_id)    
    ioform = crud.create(db.slide)
    if ioform.process(formname="ioform"):
        pass

    return dict(video=video, sources=sources, slides=slides,
                presentation=presentation_id, ioform=ioform,
                templates=templates)


@auth.requires_login()
def subtitles():
    mylanguage = session.options["language"]
    if not mylanguage: response.flash = T("No language selected! Please visit the Setup page")    

    video = db.video[request.args(1)]
    sources = db(db.source.video_id==request.args(1)).select()

    # Custom form for editing subtitles client-side
    ioform = crud.create(db.subtitle)
    if ioform.process(formname="ioform"):
        pass

    sq = db.subtitulation.user_id == auth.user_id
    sq &= db.subtitulation.video_id == request.args(1)
    sq &= db.subtitulation.language == mylanguage
    subtitulation = db(sq).select().first()

    if subtitulation is None:
        subtitulation_id = db.subtitulation.insert(user_id=auth.user_id,
                                                   video_id=request.args(1),
                                                   language=mylanguage)

        # Fill subtitulation with previous subtitles
        other_subs = db((db.subtitulation.video_id==request.args(1)) & \
                        (db.subtitulation.language==mylanguage) & \
                        (db.subtitulation.id!=subtitulation_id)).select()
        sub_qties = dict()

        for osub in other_subs:
            subcount = db(db.subtitle.subtitulation_id==osub.id).count()
            sub_qties[subcount] = osub.id

        if len(sub_qties) > 0:
            other_subs_id = sub_qties[max(sub_qties)]
            other_subtitles = db(db.subtitle.subtitulation_id==other_subs_id).select()
            for other_subtitle in other_subtitles:
                osad = other_subtitle.as_dict()
                del(osad["id"])
                del(osad["subtitulation_id"])
                osad["subtitulation_id"] = subtitulation_id
                db.subtitle.insert(**osad)
        else:
            # This is the first subtitulation for this language
            # set as default
            db.subtitulation[subtitulation_id].update_record(auto=True)
    else:
        subtitulation_id = subtitulation.id

    subs_set = db(db.subtitle.subtitulation_id==subtitulation_id)
    subtitles = subs_set.select()

    return dict(video=video, sources=sources, subtitles=subtitles,
                subtitulation=subtitulation_id, ioform=ioform)

def show():
    mypresentation = request.args(3)
    subtitles = slides = None
    language = session.options["language"]
    video = db.video[request.args(1)]
    sources = db(db.source.video_id==request.args(1)).select()
    subtitulation = db((db.subtitulation.video_id==request.args(1))&(db.subtitulation.language==session.options["language"])).select().first()
    if subtitulation:
        subtitles = db(db.subtitle.subtitulation_id==subtitulation.id).select()
    presentations = db(db.presentation.video_id==video.id).select()
    mypresentations = dict()
    for presentation in presentations:
        p_user = db.auth_user[presentation.user_id]
        mypresentations[presentation.id] = T("(%(language)s): %(slides)s slides, by %(user)s") % dict(language=presentation.language, slides=db((db.slide.presentation_id==presentation.id)&(db.slide.template==False)).count(), user=str(p_user.first_name) + " " + str(p_user.last_name))
    if mypresentation:
        default_p = mypresentation
    else:
        try:
            default_p = presentations.first().id
        except AttributeError:
            default_p = None
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field("presentation", requires=IS_IN_SET(mypresentations), default=default_p))
    form.custom.submit["_value"] = T("Change")
    if form.process().accepted:
        redirect(URL(f="show", args=["video", video.id, "presentation", form.vars.presentation]))
    if mypresentation:
        presentation = db.presentation[mypresentation]
    else:
        presentation = presentations.first()
    if presentation:
        slides = db((db.slide.presentation_id==presentation.id)&(db.slide.template==False)).select()
    return dict(video=video, sources=sources, subtitles=subtitles, slides=slides, form=form,
                presentation=presentation)

def user():
    """
    exposes:
    http://..../[app]/default/user/login
    http://..../[app]/default/user/logout
    http://..../[app]/default/user/register
    http://..../[app]/default/user/profile
    http://..../[app]/default/user/retrieve_password
    http://..../[app]/default/user/change_password
    use @auth.requires_login()
        @auth.requires_membership('group name')
        @auth.requires_permission('read','table name',record_id)
    to decorate functions that need access control
    """
    return dict(form=auth())


def download():
    """
    allows downloading of uploaded files
    http://..../[app]/default/download/[filename]
    """
    return response.download(request,db)


def call():
    """
    exposes services. for example:
    http://..../[app]/default/call/jsonrpc
    decorate with @services.jsonrpc the functions to expose
    supports xml, json, xmlrpc, jsonrpc, amfrpc, rss, csv
    """
    return service()


@auth.requires_signature()
def data():
    """
    http://..../[app]/default/data/tables
    http://..../[app]/default/data/create/[table]
    http://..../[app]/default/data/read/[table]/[id]
    http://..../[app]/default/data/update/[table]/[id]
    http://..../[app]/default/data/delete/[table]/[id]
    http://..../[app]/default/data/select/[table]
    http://..../[app]/default/data/search/[table]
    but URLs must be signed, i.e. linked with
      A('table',_href=URL('data/tables',user_signature=True))
    or with the signed load operator
      LOAD('default','data.load',args='tables',ajax=True,user_signature=True)
    """
    return dict(form=crud())


@auth.requires_login()
def setup():
    messages = UL()
    managers = db(db.auth_group.role=="manager").select().first()
    if managers is None:
        managers_id = db.auth_group.insert(role="manager")
        manager_id = db.auth_membership.insert(user_id=auth.user_id, group_id=managers_id)
        messages.append(LI("You've been added to the managers group"))
    if auth.has_membership(role="manager"):
        videos_form = SQLFORM.factory()
        videos_form.element("[type=submit]").attributes["_value"] = T("Update videos")
        if videos_form.process(formname="videos_form").accepted:
            messages.append(LI(T("Added %s videos") % setup_videos()))
    else:
        videos_form = None
    options = db(db.option.user_id==auth.user_id).select().first()
    if options is None:
        options_id = db.option.insert(user_id=auth.user_id)
    else:
        options_id = options.id
    user_form = SQLFORM(db.option, options_id)
    if user_form.process(formname="user_form").accepted:
        for k, v in user_form.vars.iteritems():
            session.options[k] = v        
        messages.append(LI(T("Done!")))
    return dict(messages=messages, videos_form=videos_form,
                user_form=user_form)

@auth.requires_login()
def subtitle():
    from gluon.contrib import simplejson
    T.lazy = False
        
    if request.args(1) == "create":
        starts = seconds_to_time(request.vars.starts)
        ends = seconds_to_time(request.vars.ends)
        subtitle_id = db.subtitle.insert(subtitulation_id=request.vars.subtitulation_id,
                                         starts=starts,
                                         ends=ends)
        subtitle = db.subtitle[subtitle_id]
        option = SUBTITLE(subtitle)
        subtitle=subtitle.as_dict()
        subtitle["starts"] = str(subtitle["starts"])
        subtitle["ends"] = str(subtitle["ends"])
        subtitle["body"] = ""
        result = simplejson.dumps(dict(option=option.xml(), subtitle=subtitle))
        return result

    elif request.args(1) == "update":
        def update_record(sub):
            del(sub["startEvent"])
            del(sub["endEvent"])
            subtitulation_id = db.subtitle[sub["id"]].subtitulation_id
            authorize("subtitulation", subtitulation_id)
            db.subtitle[sub["id"]].update_record(**sub)

        payload = simplejson.loads(request.vars.data)
        if isinstance(payload, dict):
            update_record(payload)
        elif isinstance(payload, list):
            for item in payload:
                update_record(item)
        else:
            raise HTTP(500, "Unexpected data format")
        return simplejson.dumps("Done!")
    elif request.args(1) == "delete":
        subtitulation_id = db.subtitle[request.vars.id].subtitulation_id
        authorize("subtitulation", subtitulation_id)
        result = db.subtitle[request.vars.id].delete_record()
        return simplejson.dumps("ok")
    else:
        raise HTTP(501, "Not implemented")

@auth.requires_login()
def slide():
    if request.extension == "json":
        from gluon.contrib import simplejson
        T.lazy = False

        if request.args(1) == "create":
            starts = seconds_to_time(request.vars.starts)
            ends = seconds_to_time(request.vars.ends)
            if request.vars.clones:
                clones = request.vars.clones
            else:
                clones = None
            slide_id = db.slide.insert(presentation_id=request.vars.presentation_id,
                                       starts=starts,
                                       ends=ends,
                                       clones=clones)
            slide = db.slide[slide_id]
            option = SLIDE(slide)
            slide=slide.as_dict()
            slide["starts"] = str(slide["starts"])
            slide["ends"] = str(slide["ends"])
            if not clones:
                slide["clones"] = ""
            result = simplejson.dumps(dict(option=option.xml(), slide=slide))
            return result
    
        elif request.args(1) == "update":
            def update_record(myslide):
                del(myslide["startEvent"])
                del(myslide["endEvent"])
                presentation_id = db.slide[myslide["id"]].presentation_id
                authorize("presentation", presentation_id)
                db.slide[myslide["id"]].update_record(**myslide)
    
            payload = simplejson.loads(request.vars.data)
            if isinstance(payload, dict):
                update_record(payload)
            elif isinstance(payload, list):
                for item in payload:
                    update_record(item)
            else:
                raise HTTP(500, "Unexpected data format")
            return simplejson.dumps(T("Done!"))
        elif request.args(1) == "delete":
            presentation_id = db.slide[request.vars.id].presentation_id
            authorize("presentation", presentation_id)
            result = db.slide[request.vars.id].delete_record()
            return simplejson.dumps(T("Done!"))
        else:
            raise HTTP(501, T("Not implemented"))

    else:
        slides = None
        video = db.video[int(request.args(1))]
        authorize("video", video.id)
        sources = db(db.source.video_id==request.args(1)).select()
        presentation = db((db.presentation.video_id==request.args(1))).select().first()
        if presentation:
            presentation_id = presentation.id
        else:
            presentation_id = db.presentation.insert(video_id=request.args(1), title=video.title)

        db.slide.presentation_id.writable = False
        db.slide.template.default = True
        db.slide.presentation_id.default = presentation_id
        db.slide.starts.writable = db.slide.starts.readable = False
        db.slide.ends.writable = db.slide.ends.readable = False
        db.slide.clones.writable = db.slide.clones.readable = False
        form = crud.create(db.slide)
        slides = db((db.slide.presentation_id==presentation_id)&(db.slide.template==True)).select()
        return dict(video=video, sources=sources, slides=slides, form=form)

@auth.requires_login()
def video():
    action = request.args(0)
    video_id = request.args(1)
    db.video.user_id.writable = False
    if action == "update":
        video = db.video[video_id]
        authorize("video", video.id)
        form = crud.update(db.video, video_id)
    else:
        form = crud.create(db.video)
    return dict(form=form, video_id=video_id)

@auth.requires_login()
def sources():
    video = db.video[request.args(1)]
    authorize("video", video.id)
    action = request.args(3)
    source_id = request.args(5)
    if (action == "update") and source_id:
        form = crud.update(db.source, source_id)
    else:
        db.source.video_id.default = video.id
        form = crud.create(db.source)
    db.source.id.represent = lambda field, row: A(T("Edit"),
                                                _href=URL(f="sources", \
args=["video", video.id,"action", "update", "source", field]))
    sources = db(db.source.video_id==video.id).select()
    return dict(form=form, sources=sources, video=video, action=action)

@auth.requires_login()
def srt():
    do = request.args(1)
    which = request.args(3)
    errors = None
    # TODO: the user should own the subtitulation or else be a manager
    subtitulation = db.subtitulation[int(which)]
    video = db.video[subtitulation.video_id]
    if do == "import":
        response.view = "default/srt.html"
        form = SQLFORM.factory(Field("source", "upload", uploadfield=False,
                                     requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                               Field("overwrite", "boolean",
                                     default=True,
                                     comment=T("Unselect to append to current subtitles")))
        if form.process().accepted:
            result = import_from_srt(subtitulation, request.vars)
            response.flash = T("%(inserted)s records inserted. %(removed)s records removed. Error count: %(errors)s.") % \
                dict(inserted=result["inserted"],
                     removed=result["removed"],
                     errors=len(result["errors"]))
            if len(result["errors"]) > 0:
                errors = result["errors"]
        return dict(form=form,
                    subtitulation=subtitulation,
                    video=video, errors=errors)
    elif do == "export":
        sio = export_to_srt(subtitulation)
        filename = "%(title)s_%(language)s.srt" % \
            dict(title=video.title,
                 language=subtitulation.language)
        filename = filename.replace(" ", "")
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain; charset=%s" % ENCODING
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
        return sio.read()
        # .stream is not working for .srt files (rocket raises a unicode error)
        # return response.stream(sio, attachment=True, filename=filename)
    else:
        raise HTTP(501, T("The %s option is not implemented.") % do)
```